# alignItemsInColumns alternative cocos2d 3.0

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating Level Select and here is Cocos2d 2.0 calls for align Menu buttons to a grid

```
CCMenu* menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:...];
NSNumber* itemsPerRow = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
[menu alignItemsInColumns:itemsPerRow, itemsPerRow, itemsPerRow, nil];
```

What's alternative for this in Cocos2d 3.0. CCLayoutBox has only direction.. what is best way to align CCButtons to grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not the best way to align, but it works for me

```
- (CCNode *)contentNode:(NSMutableArray *)levels
{
    CCNode *node = [[CCNode alloc] init];
    CGSize bounds = [CCDirector sharedDirector].viewSize;

    for (int a = 0; a < kChapterCount; a++)
    {
        int chapterLevelCount = kLevelCount / kChapterCount;
        int chapterRowCount = chapterLevelCount / kRowCount;
        int chapterColumnCount = chapterLevelCount / chapterRowCount;

        CCLayoutBox *layout1 = [[CCLayoutBox alloc] init];
        for (int b = chapterColumnCount-1; b >= 0; b--)
        {
            CCLayoutBox *layout2 = [[CCLayoutBox alloc] init];
            for (int c = 0; c < chapterRowCount; c++)
            {
                int n = chapterLevelCount * a + (chapterRowCount * b + c);
                NSDictionary *level = levels[n];
                int levelNumber = [level[kLevelNumber] intValue] + 1;
                int levelStars  = [level[kLevelStar] intValue];
                BOOL levelLock  = [level[kLevelLocked] boolValue];

                CCButtonAction *button = levelLock ? [self lockedLevel] : [self unlockedLevel:levelNumber star:levelStars];
                [layout2 addChild: button];
            }
            layout2.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
            layout2.spacing = 10.0f;
            layout2.direction = CCLayoutBoxDirectionHorizontal;
            [layout2 layout];
            [layout1 addChild:layout2];
        }
        layout1.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
        layout1.spacing = 6.0f;
        layout1.direction = CCLayoutBoxDirectionVertical;
        [layout1 layout];
        layout1.position = ccp(a * bounds.width + bounds.width / 2, bounds.height / 2);
        [node addChild: layout1];
    }

    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's quite simply done by using not one but two or more CCLayoutBox.

Depending on your needs and extensibility, you can either have a vertical (column-based) or horizontal (row-based) "outer" CCLayoutBox.

Inside that CCLayoutBox you add other CCLayoutBox instances as children, child layout boxes have the opposite orientation. For instance if the base layout should be column-based (outer CCLayoutBox set to vertical) you would add one or more CCLayoutBox with horizontal alignment to the other CCLayoutBox. One for each row, containing the nodes for every column.

Note that whether the outer layout node is vertical or horizontal also makes a difference when it comes to alignment and spacing of the individual "cells". Best to make a simple test to see which way better suits your purposes.

Comment: I have a CCLayoutBox with 5 CCLabelTTF. I have set the CCLayoutBox direction to CCLayoutBoxDirectionVertical. I would like to left align all the labels because that are supposed to be along the left edge of the devices. Currently they are aligned in the center. I'm also trying to do this in code not with Sprite Builder.